# json.net: problems serializing type derived from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have a class that extends the basic `ObservableCollection<T>` class (adds some more properties). When I serialize the class using json.net, it omits the added properties. For example, the following class:

```
public class ObservableCollectionExt : ObservableCollection<int>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string MyData1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string MyData2 { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollectionExt()
    {
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public ObservableCollectionExt(string mydata1, string mydata2)
    {
        MyData1 = mydata1;
        MyData2 = mydata2;
    }

    public static ObservableCollectionExt Create()
    {
        ObservableCollectionExt coll = new ObservableCollectionExt("MyData1", "MyData2");

        coll.Add(1);
        coll.Add(2);
        coll.Add(3);

        return coll;
    }

}
```

gets serialized as follows (with values for `MyData1` and `MyData2` missing):

{
  "$type": "Test1.ObservableCollectionExt, Test1",
  "$values": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}

How can I include the extra properties in the serialized data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a custom converter. Not sure that this is the best way to do it, but it seems to work.

```
        public class MyCustomConverter : JsonConverter
        {
            public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
            {
                return objectType == typeof(ObservableCollectionExt);
            }

            public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                ObservableCollectionExt result = new ObservableCollectionExt();
                string type = null;
                int i;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
                        type = reader.Value.ToString();
                    else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject)
                        return result;
                    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type) && reader.Value != null)
                    {
                        switch (type)
                        {
                            case "mydata1":
                                {
                                    result.MyData1 = reader.Value.ToString();
                                    break;
                                }
                            case "mydata2":
                                {
                                    result.MyData2 = reader.Value.ToString();
                                    break;
                                }
                            case "elements":
                                {
                                    if (int.TryParse(reader.Value.ToString(), out i))
                                        result.Add(i);
                                    break;
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                ObservableCollectionExt o = (ObservableCollectionExt)value;

                writer.WriteStartObject();

                writer.WritePropertyName("mydata1");
                writer.WriteValue(o.MyData1);

                writer.WritePropertyName("mydata2");
                writer.WriteValue(o.MyData2);

                writer.WritePropertyName("elements");
                writer.WriteStartArray();
                foreach (var val in o)
                    writer.WriteValue(val);
                writer.WriteEndArray();

                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }
        }
```

This produces strings like this: `{\"mydata1\":\"MyData1\",\"mydata2\":\"MyData2\",\"elements\":[1,2,3]}`

Use the converter like this:

```
        ObservableCollectionExt o = ObservableCollectionExt.Create();
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Converters.Add(new MyCustomConverter());
        string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, settings);
        ObservableCollectionExt deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollectionExt>(serialized, settings);
```

**EDIT:**

I realize the converter would only work for simple cases when the custom properties are not complex types. There is another way, a workaround with an anonymous type:

```
    ObservableCollectionExt o = ObservableCollectionExt.Create();
    string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { MyData1 = o.MyData1, MyData2 = o.MyData2, coll = o });
    var anonType = new { MyData1 = null as object, MyData2 = null as object, coll = null as object };
    dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(serialized, anonType);
    ObservableCollectionExt deserialized = new ObservableCollectionExt(d.MyData1, d.MyData2);
    foreach (var elem in d.coll)
        deserialized.Add((int)elem);
```

Comment: using a converter works, but, since the extra properties, in my case, are actually other complex types, I would have to write serialization/deserialization code for all of them -- quite a daunting task! I am hoping there's a simpler solution.